# getting only inner keys from a nested dictionary

Tags: python-2.7

i have the data in json file in this form

```
 [
    {
        "FIRST NAME": "Nasim",
        "EMAIL": "ac@iaculisnec.net",
        "ADDLINE1": "855-8805 Nunc. Avenue",
        "CITY": "Masterton",
        "LOCATION":{"ADDLINE2":"855-8805",
                    "ADDLINE3":"Avenue",
                    "PIN":"100",
                    "ZIP":{"AREA":"5645",
                           "STREET":"hgh",
                           "MAIN":"87"
                    }}
    },
    {
        "FIRST NAME": "Xanthus",
        "EMAIL": "adipiscing.elit@tinciduntcongue.edu",
        "ADDLINE1": "357-4583 Curae; St.",
        "CITY": "Basildon",
        "LOCATION":{"ADDLINE2":"357-4583",
                    "ADDLINE3":"Curae; St.",
                    "PIN":"101",
                    "ZIP":{"AREA":"546",
                           "STREET":"yjtyj",
                           "MAIN":"56"
                   }}
    }
```

how do i list out only the keys in this form 
**FIRSTNAME
EMAIL
ADDLINE1
CITY
LOCATION{ADDLINE2,ADDLINE3,PIN,ZIP{AREA,STREET,MAIN}}**

i have implemented this

```
for key in row.iterkeys():
    print key 
    for items in row[key]:
        print items
```

but i'm getting even the values along with it. even if the depth increases it should be able to list out all the subkeys.
need the output in this form

```
FIRSTNAME
LOCATION
  ADDLINE2
  ADDLINE3
  PIN
  ZIP
    STREET
    MAIN
    AREA
ADDRESS
EMAIL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following recursive method:

```
def get_keys(d):
    for key in d.iterkeys():
        yield key
        if isinstance(d[key], dict):
            yield list(get_keys(d[key]))

for row in data:
    print list(get_keys(row))
```

With `data` being your nested dictionary, this gives you this output:

```
['ADDLINE1', 'FIRST NAME', 'LOCATION', ['ADDLINE3', 'ADDLINE2', 'ZIP', ['STREET', 'MAIN', 'AREA'], 'PIN'], 'EMAIL', 'CITY']
['ADDLINE1', 'FIRST NAME', 'LOCATION', ['ADDLINE3', 'ADDLINE2', 'ZIP', ['STREET', 'MAIN', 'AREA'], 'PIN'], 'EMAIL', 'CITY']
```

Note that the ordering of the keys can be different than in the original dictionary, as there is no guarantee in what order `d.iterkeys()` (or any other similar method) will produce the keys.

If you want to turn those into strings in the format shown in your question, you could use this:

```
def to_string(keys):
    return " ".join("{" + to_string(key) + "}" if isinstance(key, list) else key.replace(" ", "") for key in keys)
```

Result would be `ADDLINE1 FIRSTNAME LOCATION {ADDLINE3 ADDLINE2 ZIP {STREET MAIN AREA} PIN} EMAIL CITY`. Note that this collapses keys like `FIRST NAME` to `FIRSTNAME` (as you did in your example), otherwise you need to use some other delimiter than `" "`, e.g. use `", ".join(...)` instead. Personally, I'd rather leave it as a list, and *not* turn it into a string.

Comment: thanks a lot.. didn't know that instance can be used.

Comment: how can i convert it to string so that i will get the output in this form

Answer (score 0):

A recursive solution might be:

```
def getkeys(x):
    result = []
    for k, v in x.items():
        result.append(k)
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            result += getkeys(v)
    return result

map(getkeys, your_json_objects_list)
```

> [['ADDLINE1', 'FIRST NAME', 'LOCATION', 'ADDLINE3', 'ADDLINE2', 'ZIP',
>   'STREET',  'MAIN', 'AREA', 'PIN', 'EMAIL', 'CITY'], ['ADDLINE1',
>   'FIRST NAME', 'LOCATION',  'ADDLINE3', 'ADDLINE2', 'ZIP', 'STREET',
>   'MAIN', 'AREA', 'PIN', 'EMAIL', 'CITY' ]]

Comment: I think he wants the keys as a nested list, not as a flat list.

Comment: You might be right. The example looks like a weird mixture of list and dict to me...